# Wordpress failed to load bootstrap 4

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, resources

Wordpress failed to load bootstrap 4 it shows version in console

```
 wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/boostrap.css');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try get_stylesheet_directory_uri()

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '', true );
```